# Llenar un Textbox mediante un item seleccionado en un ComboBox C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

Tengo una base de Datos en Access en la cual existen 2 campos llamados `Base de Datos` y otra que se llama `Tipo de Usuario`. Quisiera que al momento de seleccionar un item en el combobox, aparezca en el textbox de `Tipo de Usuario` el tipo de usuario que es. Hay 2 posibles opciones *Administrador* o *Usuario*. Entiendo un poco la lógica que debo usar, el código que utilizo es el siguiente pero me arroja un error, el cual dice que faltan algunos parámetros, los cual no logro entender a que se refiere. De ante mano, gracias.

```
private void base_de_DatosComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection cnx = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\BD_Usuarios.accdb");

        try
        {
            cnx.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = cnx;
            string query = "select * from Usuarios where Tipo_de_Usuario='"+base_de_DatosComboBox.Text+"';";
            command.CommandText = query;

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                tipo_de_UsuarioTextBox.Text = reader["Tipo de Usuario"].ToString();
            }
            cnx.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Adjunto una foto del error:

[image: Foto]

Comment: Podrías ayudarnos agregando el código de error

Comment: Error.System.Data.OleDB.OleDb.Exception: No value given for one or more required parameters at 
System.Data.OleDb.OledbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling (oleDbHresultHr)

Comment: Ese error te aparece cuando abres por primera vez la ventana que contiene al ComboBox? En qué momento y bajo que condiciones ocurre este error? El mensaje de error indica que hay un parámetro en la consulta que no estás incluyendo. Me parece que el texto que incluyes del ComboBox, al momento de contruir la consulta, se encuentra en blanco, por lo tanto, la sentencia WHERE quedaría sin parámetro alguno y te arrojaría ese error.

Comment: Revisa el valor de `base_de_DatosComboBox.Text`

Answer (score 1):

Parece que tu error puede venir de que estas intentando recojer los datos de una columna no existente en la tabla.

Fijandome en el código que nos muestras me fijo en que en la query SQL pones:

```
select * from Usuarios where Tipo_de_Usuario='"+base_de_DatosComboBox.Text+"';
```

Teniendo en el WHERE la columna `Tipo_de_Usuario` y en el reader tienes lo siguiente:

```
reader["Tipo de Usuario"].ToString();
```

Si te fijas, no estas cogiendo la columna correctamente ya que la del reader no lleva los `_`.

Tu reader debería quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
reader["Tipo_de_Usuario"].ToString();
```